# Wi-Fi Calling: Straight talk iPhone 6s with T-Mobile SIM

Tags: iphone, wifi, unlock, sim

Wi-Fi calling [requires an iPhone 5c or newer](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203032).

I would like to migrate from ST to TMO with a 6s.  As I understand it [both carriers support Wi-Fi calling](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204039#usa).  Assuming that the 6s is SIM unlocked, what are the steps to reconfigure the 6s to enable wifi calling with a TMO SIM card?